# This page isn’t working localhost didn’t send any data. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a problem. when try to run my dockerFile in React app.
When I try to run my DockerFile

```
FROM node:16

ENV REACT_APP_baseUrl = https://localhost:44377/api
ENV REACT_APP_baseUrlFile = https://localhost:3000/files
ENV REACT_APP_baseUrlFileMetadata = https://localhost:3000/files/metaData
ENV REACT_APP_FILESTORAGE_KEY = ./fileStorage.key
ENV REACT_APP_FILESTORAGE_PEM = ./fileStorage.pem
ENV REACT_APP_ROOT_CA = ./rootCA.pem
ENV REACT_APP_baseUrlReact = http://localhost:8080

WORKDIR /app-ui

COPY package.json ./
COPY yarn.lock ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
COPY ./ ./
RUN yarn install
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

Then I run:

```
docker build -f Dockerfile -t client .
docker run -it -p 8080:8080 client
```

And get

[image: error page]

But I do not understand the problem.
Please help

I can provide container status
[image]

Comment: Can you provide the status of the docker container? (`docker ps`)

Comment: Yes. I can. I edit my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not specify the that CRA should use for the development server. You can do so with the `-e` as such:

```bash
docker run -it -p 8080:8080 -e "PORT=8080" client
```

Comment: It works! THANK UOU. Can you please say, how can I add this -e in docker-compose?

Comment: @MariaKamenskyh Happy to answer but not over the comment section, get back to me with a link to a new question!